# C error: expected expression before '||' token

Tags: c

Here is my code for the function merge:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "merge.h"


void merge(
    char a1[], int n1,
    char a2[], int n2,
    char output[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int z = 0;

    while (i < n1) || (j < n2)  // This is where the error happends
    {
        if (i < n1) && (j < n2)
        if (a1[i] <= a2[j])
                output[z++] = a1[i++];
        else
            output[z++] = a2[j++];

        else if (j == n2)
         while (i < n1)
              output[z++] = a1[i++];

    else if (i == n1)
         while (j < n2)
              output[z++] = a2[j++];
     }
}
```

Could you tell me why the code has this error? I have looked at all the questions with this same error but it seems like there was no universal answer for this error...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hai, just a sidenote: please be careful with variable increments inside brackets: [z++]. You should know that [z++] while use output[z] and then will increment it, while [++z] will first increment < and then output[z], so in this last case z will be incremented before accessing to output.

Comment: Hi Didac, I'm trying to merge two arrays a1 and a2 into the array output. Therefore, every time output[z] gets a value, z will increment so that output[z+1] can also get a value. Do you mean I should be mindful of the fact that even after I have merged all the elements from a1 and a2 into output, z would still increment? Does that really matter? Because even though z still increments by 1, this time output[z] will not be assigned any value because all elements from a1 and a2 have already been merged. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Englobe the full condition between brackets:

```
while ((i < 3) || (j < 3))
```

You can also use:

```
while (i < 3 || j < 3)
```

And be carefully with:

```
if (i < n1) && (j < n2)
```

which may be:

```
if (i < n1 && j < n2)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
while (i < 3) || (j < 3)
```

should be:

```
while ((i < 3) || (j < 3))
```

or (because `<` has a higher precedence than `||`)

```
while (i < 3 || j < 3)
```

Comment: +1 for "or (because < has a higher precedence than ||)"

Answer (score 1):

```
while (i < 3) || (j < 3)
```

should be

```
while ((i < 3) || (j < 3))
```

same for

```
if (i < n1) && (j < n2)
```