# Error: expected expression before '||' token

Tags: c

I would like to know what's wrong with my code. Are there problems with or statement ( || ) or is there something else wrong with my code. The error that it gives me is: [Error] expected expression before '||' token

```
    if (DH>YH>=K) || (DH>K>=YH)
        {
        printf("Soodsaim variant on osta %f päevapiletit.\n", P);
        }
```

Comment: stack overflow is no debugging service.

Comment: Simple syntax error, your parentheses around your if expressions are broken. You need to parenethesize your whole conditions, a'la `if ( (DH>YH>=K) || (DH>K>=YH) )`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26175157/694576

Answer (score 3):

Once you get the parens right, `DH>YH>=K` probably doesn't mean what you think it means. `DH>YH` produces either 0 or 1, and then that's compared to `K`.

You'll want to write `DH>YH && YH>=K`.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go. It should work fine. :)

```
#include <stdio.h>



int main()
{
    float P, S, Y, D, K, DH, YH;
    printf("Sisestage päevade arv:\n");
    scanf("%f", &P);
    printf("Sisestage sõitude arv:\n");
    scanf("%f", &S);
    printf("Sisestage ühekordse pileti hind:\n");
    scanf("%f", &Y);
    printf("Sisestage päeva pileti hind:\n");
    scanf("%f", &D);
    printf("Sisestage kuukaardi hind:\n");
    scanf("%f", &K);
    DH = P*D;
    YH = Y*S;
    if ((DH>YH>=K) || (DH>K>=YH))
        {
        printf("Soodsaim variant on osta %f päevapiletit.\n", P);
        }
    else
        if ((YH>DH>=K) || (YH>K>=DH))
        {
        printf("Soodsaim variant on osta %f ühekordset piletit.\n", S);
        }
    else
        if ((K>DH>=YH) || (K>YH>=DH))
        {
            printf("Soodsaim variant on kuukaart.\n");
        }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Oh, i'm surprised that i didn't notice that mistake. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: Best of luck mate. :) @MihkelKull